# Are Erina Nakiri and Sōma Yukihira relatives?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

In the anime, Nakiri is waiting for Jōichirō Yukihira to come, why is that? Is it possible that Nakiri is related to Soma? Because we don't know anything about their mothers?

Comment: This is explained in manga which is bit ahead of anime, just hang on tight

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Still not explained if there is a relation between Erina and Soma. We don't know who their Moms are...

Answer (score 2):

It's because Joichiro is like an influence to Erina and he is really dear to her and also he agreed to taste her cooking when she becomes a good chef. And also no, Yukihira Soma and Erina Nakiri are not relatives.

Comment: I got the influence part from the anime, but how that happened I mean nakiri and joichiro become so close?

Comment: Actually, since we don't know the identity of who are the Moms of Erina and Souma, we can't be sure they are not related. Yukihira is likely the name of Soma's Mother's family since both Gin and Azami recognised the name, but didn't associate with Saiba Joichiro.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in chapter 168 of the manga. It is stated in the [Wiki](https://shokugekinosoma.fandom.com/wiki/J%C5%8Dichir%C5%8D_Yukihira#History) that,

> At the age of 28, Jōichirō was summoned to the Nakiri Mansion by Senzaemon to discuss a matter of importance. During his visit, he met a young Erina Nakiri. Though Senzaemon told her to go back to her room so he could continue to discuss something with Jōichirō, Erina's stomach growled. Jōichirō immediately prepared a dish just for her and with a single bite, Erina was completely enthralled not just by the unique taste of his dish, but also by Jōichirō's charm. This event became a turning point in Erina's life and she requested for a photo of the two together, a notion Jōichirō happily obliged. She also asked for his name and if he would ever taste her dishes. Jōichirō promised he would only do so when she becomes a great chef herself.